# Drawing data from adb framebuffer using GDI+

Tags: android, c++, gdi+, gdi

Is there any way to convert framebuffer, which is received from adb service to draw its as a image on screen (using GDI or GDI+)

I can get data from adb service and store it in struct below: (the data structure is extracted from adb/framebuffer_service.cpp)

```
struct fb {
    unsigned int bpp;
    unsigned int size;
    unsigned int width;
    unsigned int height;
    unsigned int red_offset;
    unsigned int red_length;
    unsigned int blue_offset;
    unsigned int blue_length;
    unsigned int green_offset;
    unsigned int green_length;
    unsigned int alpha_offset;
    unsigned int alpha_length;
    void* data;
};
```

Answer (score 0):

A custom `Bitmap` can be created using [GDI+: Bitmap.LockBits method](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms536298(v=vs.85).aspx).

After `LockBits` you can access the individual pixels and their components (red, green, blue, alpha channel).

First create a empty `Bitmap` of required size and then use `LockBits` to overwrite the pixel data with new values.

Comment: Thank you for for answering, now I can draw in but how to speedup socket connection, it is quite slow (about 1 second to get framebuffer from adb server).

Comment: @user3614759: For how to speed up the data transfer, please open a new question mentioning what data are you trying to transfer, what its format and all the necessary things related to data.